# Player's turn is skipped and winner is not displayed in Python Connect 4 game

Tags: python, exception

I recently started taking a python class and we are currently working on a project based off the game Connect Four. I have almost everything done except for 2 bugs I can not seem to find a solution to. The following code should allow 2 players (Red and Yellow) to drop a "coin" or pop a "coin". However, Red player always goes first (which my code already does allow) but when the player is asked if they want to drop(d) or pop(p) a coin and they mistype "d" or "p" the program skips the current players turn BUT when the coin is dropped(d) the other color is still reflected.

Also when one of the players has won, the program keeps going and would ask the following player to drop or pop a coin and then it will end.

[In this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcQHn.jpg), you can see how its yellows turn and they drop(d) in column 2 the coin(Y) drops. Then its player Reds turn and they mistype drop(d) it gives them a warning and then when asked the same question the player name is skipped to Yellow BUT when the player drops(d) a coin it is still reds coin(r). Then, after the coin is dropped technically it would be player Yellow but the name appears to red but the coin will still drop in "Y".

Here is a section of my program. This is the section of my program is where I am struggling in:

```
def play(game: GameState, col_len: int) -> None:
    while winner(game) == 0:
        while True:
            for player in itertools.cycle(['Red', 'Yellow']):
                move = input(player + ' Drop (D) or Pop(P): ')
                if move.upper() == 'D':
                    try:
                        col = int(input(f'Column(1-{col_len}): '))
                        game = drop(game, col - 1)
                        print(f'Success! Drop column {col}')
                        display_board(game.board)
                    except ValueError:
                        print('Invalid! Out of range.')
                        col = int(input(f'try again! Column(1-{col_len}): '))
                elif move.upper() == 'P':
                    try:
                        col = int(input(f'Column(1-{col_len}): '))
                        game = pop(game, col - 1)
                        print(f'Success! Pop column {col}')
                        display_board(game.board)
                    except ValueError:
                        print('Invalid! Out of range.')
                        col = int(input(f'try again! Column(1-{col_len}): '))
                else:
                    print('Wrong movement! Try again.')
    print('Winner Red' if winner(game) == 1 else 'Winner Yellow' if winner(game) == 2 else 'Empty')
```

Comment: Why do you have `while True:` if you want the loop to stop?

Comment: The nested loops are confusing and won't do what you want. Think about when you want to advance to the next player. Then look at when your code moves to the next player. Think about when you want to check if the game is over. Then look at when your code checks that.

Comment: I used a while True: because I thought it will run and stop when the game was over? sorry I am still new at this.